# Diskpart batch file to auto mount and format the disk

Tags: batch-file

i have a requirement in my project i.e a cloud portal 
we have the provision to attach an additional disk on the fly in windows virtual machine.
to automate the mounting ,i have written a batch file .that mounts and format the disk.
problem is that it works fine , but in windows server 2008 although after auto confirming it as to format the disk . though my mount and format command works and disk get attached and converted to NTFS. but that dialog box is very annoying ...please help my batch file is like this

```
@echo off 
rem # the following batch file is used to create dynamic disk , mount it and format it
echo>tempdiskpart.txt List disk
diskpart /s tempdiskpart.txt > tempdiskfilelist.txt
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c /i "Disk" "tempdiskfilelist.txt"') do set isComplete=%%f
set /a total = %isComplete%-3

rem # code to find driver letter 
set /a diskNum =1
:loop
set w=s

if exist e:\nul echo. Disk in use

rem for %%p in (d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%p:\nul echo. %%p Disk in use
for %%p in (z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d) do if exist %%p:\nul echo. %%p Disk in use
for %%p in (z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d) do if not exist %%p:\nul echo. %%p Disk is available
for %%p in (z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d) do if not exist %%p:\nul set driveltr=%%p



 echo > tempdiskpart%total%.txt Select Disk %total%
 echo >> tempdiskpart%total%.txt convert dynamic
 echo >> tempdiskpart%total%.txt create volume simple Disk %total%
 echo >> tempdiskpart%total%.txt assign letter=%driveltr%
 diskpart /s tempdiskpart%total%.txt
 del tempdiskpart%total%.txt
 echo >tempdiskvolume%total%.bat 
 echo >>tempdiskvolume%total%.bat format %driveltr%: /v:Newdisk_%diskNum% /FS:ntfs /q
 echo Y |call tempdiskvolume%total%.bat 
 del tempdiskvolume%total%.bat

  set /a diskNum +=1
  set /a total -=1


  if %total% GTR 0 goto loop

   del tempdiskfilelist.txt
   del tempdiskpart.txt
```

i hope this file helps somebody to automate the process. please help me to complete it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change this line:

```
echo >>tempdiskvolume%total%.bat format %driveltr%: /v:Newdisk_%diskNum% /FS:ntfs /q
```

into this:

```
echo >>tempdiskvolume%total%.bat echo y ^| format %driveltr%: /v:Newdisk_%diskNum% /FS:ntfs /q
```

This is like the `echo Y |call tempdiskvolume%total%.bat` line, except that since we want to generate a pipe character, we just need to escape it using the `^` character.